# Why doesn't WebRTC send any data after successful ICE?

Tags: webrtc

I'm trying to make the WebRTC example work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation

My code is exactly the same. I use a websocket as the signaler and a Python websocket server.
My HTML is the following:

```html
<video class=selfview></video>
<video class=remoteview></video>
```

I set the first tab A as polite and the second B as not polite.

Then I call the `start()` method in A.

This is the log on my server, the boolean at the beginning of the line indicates the "polite" flag of the originating client: https://pastebin.com/V9pj0VNb

I think the ICE is successful as `pc.iceConnectionState` is true on both sides.

By debugging, I have come to the conclusion that `pc.ontrack` is called in B (twice), and it is also called in A if I `start()` in B.

After calling `start()` in a tab, a picture from my camera appears and I can make it move in real time by calling `selfVideo.play()`.

However, `track.onunmute` is never called on any side, making it look like no data is transmitting. I spent the last 2 hours trying everything I could think of but I really have no idea.

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with my version of Firefox: https://gitlab.manjaro.org/manjaro-arm/packages/extra/firefox/-/issues/1